# FFMPEG slow / fast motion part a video anywhere

Tags: video, ffmpeg

am trying to cut a part of Video

Here is the code i have tried Let's say i have 6 seconds video and i want to slow down 2:5 seconds video that 3 second video

First approach after searching is, Cut the video, then apply slow filter then concat it with original video. But this is a mid part not entire video. How can i modify below code

> ffmpeg -i Soon.mp4 -filter_complex
>   [0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v1]setpts=0.5PTS[v1];[0:a]atempo=2[a]
>   concat=n=1:v=1:a=1 -map "[v]" -map "[a] -preset superfast -profile:v
>   baseline output.mp4

Answer (score 12):

This slows down one part of a video and keeps the rest as is.

```
ffmpeg -i Soon.mp4
  -filter_complex
     "[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
      [0:v]trim=2:5,setpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v2];
      [0:v]trim=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3];
      [0:a]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
      [0:a]atrim=2:5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.5[a2];
      [0:a]atrim=5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a3];
      [v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][a3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1"
  -preset superfast -profile:v baseline output.mp4
```

How does it work?

- The `trim` and `atrim` filters cut the video into different parts, from 0–2 seconds, from 2–5, and from 5 to the end.
- In each part a `setpts`/`asetpts` filter is applied, which, when using the option `PTS-STARTPTS`, "resets" the presentation timestamps of each frame in each part, so that they can later be concatenated easily.
- Each part is given an output label (e.g. `[v1]` through `[v3]`).
- For the video parts that need to be slowed down, every presentation timestamp is doubled (`2*(…)`), which effectively halves the speed of the video. If you wanted to speed up the video, use a multiplier lower than 1.
- For audio parts to be sped up / slowed down, use the `atempo` filter, whose parameter is the speedup (e.g., `0.5` = half speed).
- These parts are finally concatenated using the `concat` filter.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this code :) can u please explain this part [0:a]atrim=2:5,asetpts=2*(PTS-STARTPTS),atempo=0.5[a2]; what is 2 and 0.5?

Comment: If you're slowing down part of a video, you'll want to slow down corresponding audio as well. But not the other parts of the audio. That 2 is not needed. Removed. 0.05 is to slow down the audio by 2.

Comment: **Note:** `-preset superfast -profile:v baseline` will usually result in very bad quality and/or high file sizes. Unless you know that you need these options, it's better to *not* use them and let ffmpeg use the default settings.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gyan's answer! Taking that plus a bit research, I have applied it to speed up a video with audio by 6 times. Be aware that atempo argument has a value ranging between 0.5 and 2. So three atempo were used to make up 6 (2 x 2 x 1.5). So the idea is to make the video from 00:00:00 to 00:17:30, a total of 1050 seconds, to play 6 times faster and the rest stays unchanged. Code example as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i in_file.mp4 -filter_complex \
   "[0:v]trim=0:1050,setpts=1/6*(PTS-STARTPTS)[v1];\
   [0:v]trim=1050,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];\
   [0:a]atrim=0:1050,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=1.5[a1];\
   [0:a]atrim=1050,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];\
   [v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" \
   output_file.mp4
```

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/21804/10727

Answer (score 0):

@ slhck

[This slows down one part of a video and keeps the rest as is.](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21800/ffmpeg-slow-fast-motion-part-a-video-anywhere/21804#21804)

I've never seen `PTS-STARTPTS` before. I have always used just `PTS` for this purpose. I have a recent script that hangs with just `PTS` but it works with `PTS-STARTPTS`. Can you explain why?

With `PTS`

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" \
-filter_complex \
" \
[0:v]trim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',setpts=4*PTS,curves=psfile=curves40.acv,unsharp=13:13:1.5:13:13:1.5[v0]; \
[0:a]atrim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',asetpts=PTS,atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5[a0]; \
[0:v]trim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',reverse,setpts=4*PTS,curves=psfile=curves40.acv,unsharp=13:13:1.5:13:13:1.5[v1]; \
[0:a]atrim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',areverse,asetpts=PTS,atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5[a1]; \
[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out] \
" \
-map "[out]" \
-r $fps -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 10 -map_chapters -1 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 \
-movflags faststart "otput.mp4"
```

With `PTS-STARTPTS`

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" \
-filter_complex \
" \
[0:v]trim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',setpts=4*(PTS-STARTPTS),curves=psfile=curves40.acv,unsharp=13:13:1.5:13:13:1.5[v0]; \
[0:a]atrim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5[a0]; \
[0:v]trim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',reverse,setpts=4*(PTS-STARTPTS),curves=psfile=curves40.acv,unsharp=13:13:1.5:13:13:1.5[v1]; \
[0:a]atrim='00\:08\:23.961':'00\:08\:24.379',areverse,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,atempo=0.5,atempo=0.5[a1]; \
[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out] \
" \
-map "[out]" \
-r $fps -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 10 -map_chapters -1 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -pix_fmt yuv420p -codec:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k -r:a 48000 \
-movflags faststart "otput.mp4"
```

In both cases I get `frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x` but it works in this case.